# Pending/Approved/Denied workflow security for Java

Tags: java, web-applications

I'm have implemented a module for Java web application that users will need to request for them to access the secured data. It works like this: when users that does not yet have access clicks on a certain link, a request is made and is received on the server side. It now generates an email and sends to people who are "approvers". The email contain links on approving or denying the access of that user.

**Approved Link**:`http://hostname/App_name?action=actionClass&approved=true`
**Denied Link**:`http://hostname/App_name?action=actionClass&approved=false`

Now the question is, is there a better way to do this which also takes into consideration the security?

I did try to look for other posts that are related to this but the results don't seem to be touching on this regard. If there are any that I have missed, I would appreciate if you can also point them so I can revise the question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You definitely don't want something like ``approved=false`` in the URL, since the first thing someone will try is manually changing it to true - so you have to at least not trust the URL.  

What is supposed to happen with the denied link - why would someone click it?

Comment: Tim, the links are for the use of superusers but I am afraid that what you said about the URL is the case. I'm open for any suggestions to not have to do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that you are authenticating the users when they click on the given link, because otherwise it's just bad mojo.

You can have some privileges assigned to that user and check that to see if you are going to allow the approve or not.

Comment: Thihara, Yes that is already in place. Users are already authenticated  before they can see the page so I guess that covers it

Comment: In that case I don't see the issue. Even though anyone can fake the URL they won't have the necessary privilege you will be checking right?????

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood your answer. What I'm trying to say is that all employees of the company, when using web apps, are authenticated and from the application, the user id, name, etc are made available. In this case, since all employees can access the application, it does not mean that they can access this specific app that I'm working on so they would need approval and thus back to the question above.

Comment: You need Privileges and Roles assigned to each user.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you are sending out the email. Assuming you are doing it client-side, then  a user could intercept their own approval link, which clearly you don't want.

A better way (assuming you aren't doing this already) would be to send the user information (via HTTPS of course) to your server and then have the server generate and send the email. This way no one has access to the approval link except those emailed by the server and those in control of the server (you hopefully).

Comment: Matthew, Thank  you for the input. The email is already generated in the server. What you have described is actually what we have, though we are not using https and we wouldn't need any user info since we have a corporate location where to get needed information about the user.